# What could make odoo have a JavaScript error: Unsupported operator "not like" in domain

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

So when I added a new field, shower_form, to jobshop.xml which ties to tickets.py, it is supposed to appear when one selects shower from manage_jobs.xml.
It does work, only that this code breaks my JavaScript for the whole application and gives an error in the browser's console "Unsupported operator not like in domain". Any idea what causes this error?

[Browser console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/20VVW.png)

**jobshop.xml**

```
<field name="shower_form" attrs="{'invisible':[('type','not in',['shower'])]}"/>
```

**tickets.py**

```
shower_form = fields.One2many('jobshop.shower_order_form', 'ticket_id', string='Fill Shower Order Form?',
                               help='Does this ticket needs a shower order form?',
)
```

**manage_jobs.xml**

```
<t t-if="widget.ticket_type == 'shower'">
                <option value="shower_form">Shower Order form</option>
            </t>
```

**shower_form.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<template id="assets_backend" name="jobshop.shower_order_form assets" inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
  <xpath expr="." position="inside">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href="/jobshop/static/src/css/shower.css"/>
  </xpath>
</template>
<!-- Form View -->
<record id="ticket_shower_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
  <field name="name">jobshop.shower_form</field>
  <field name="model">jobshop.shower_order_form</field>
  <field name="priority">15</field>
  <field name="arch" type="xml">
    <form string="Shower Form">
      <sheet>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                Shower Order Form
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
        <group class="container">
          <div class="row m-3">
            <div class="col-md-9">
              <h2 class="display-5">Store</h2>
              <h3 class="display-5 text-muted">SHOWER ORDER FORM</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <label for="date" class="col-sm-4 control-label"/>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <field name="date" placeholder="Date"/>
              </div>
              <label for="sales_rep" class="col-sm-4 control-label"/>
              <div class="col-sm-8">
                <field name='sales_rep' />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </group>
        <group class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="panel panel-default col-xs-6 col-md-6">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <label for="customer" class="col-sm-5 control-label"/>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                  <field name="customer" placeholder="Customer"/>
                </div>
                <label for="address" class="col-sm-5 control-label"/>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                  <field name="address" placeholder="Address"/>
                </div>
                <label for="project" class="col-sm-5 control-label"/>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                  <field name="project" placeholder="Project"/>
                </div>
                <label for="lot" class="col-sm-5 control-label"/>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                  <field name="lot" placeholder="Lot#"/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default col-xs-6 col-md-6">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <label for="deliver_address" class="col-sm-5 control-label"/>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                  <field name="deliver_address" placeholder="Delivery Address"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-inline row">
                  <div class="form-group col-sm-8 row">
                    <label for="install_date" class="col-sm-5 clearfix"/>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                      <field name="install_date" placeholder=""/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="checkbox col-sm-4 row">
                    <label for="ready_now" class="col-sm-8 clearfix"/>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                      <field name="ready_now" placeholder=""/>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <label for="telephone" class="col-sm-5 control-label"/>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                  <field name="telephone" placeholder="Telephone"/>
                </div>
                <label for="superintendent_num" class="col-sm-5 control-label"/>
                <div class="col-sm-7">
                  <field name="superintendent_num" placeholder="Superintendent Num"/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </group>
        <group class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th class="vertical">
                      <span class="vertical">Numbers</span>
                    </th>
                    <th class="vertical">
                      <span class="vertical">Size</span>
                    </th>
                    <th class="vertical">
                      <span class="vertical">Chrome</span>
                    </th>
                    <th class="vertical">
                      <span class="vertical">Plate</span>
                    </th>
                    <th class="vertical">
                      <span class="vertical">BN</span>
                    </th>
                    <th class="vertical">
                      <span class="vertical">Champ</span>
                    </th>
                    <th class="vertical">
                      <span class="vertical">Brushed Nickel</span>
                    </th>
                    <th class="vertical">
                      <span class="vertical">Oil Rubbed</span>
                    </th>
                    <th class="vertical">
                      <span class="vertical">Aged BZ</span>
                    </th>
                    <th class="vertical">
                      <span class="vertical">Aged Pewter</span>
                    </th>
                    <th class="vertical">
                      <span class="vertical">Clear</span>
                    </th>
                    <th class="vertical">
                      <span class="vertical">P62</span>
                    </th>
                    <th class="vertical">
                      <span class="vertical">Rain</span>
                    </th>
                    <th class="vertical">
                      <span class="vertical">Glue Chip</span>
                    </th>
                    <th class="vertical">
                      <span class="vertical">Gray</span>
                    </th>
                    <th class="vertical">
                      <span class="vertical">Bronze</span>
                    </th>
                    <th class="vertical">
                      <span class="vertical">Tub Bypass</span>
                    </th>
                    <th class="vertical">
                      <span class="vertical">Shower Bypass</span>
                    </th>
                    <th class="vertical">
                      <span class="vertical">Other</span>
                    </th>
                    <th class="vertical">
                      <span class="vertical">Euro Tub</span>
                    </th>
                    <th class="vertical">
                      <span class="vertical">Euro Lite Shower</span>
                    </th>
                    <th class="vertical">
                      <span class="vertical">Semi-Patch</span>
                    </th>
                    <th class="vertical">
                      <span class="vertical">Semi-Comp</span>
                    </th>
                    <th class="vertical">
                      <span class="vertical">Euro</span>
                    </th>

                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">1</th>
                    <td><field name="size"/></td>
                    <td><field name="chrome"/></td>
                    <td><field name="plate"/></td>
                    <td><field name="bn"/></td>
                    <td><field name="champ"/></td>
                    <td><field name="brushed_nickel"/></td>
                    <td><field name="oil_rubbed"/></td>
                    <td><field name="aged_bz"/></td>
                    <td><field name="aged_pewter"/></td>
                    <td><field name="clear"/></td>
                    <td><field name="p62"/></td>
                    <td><field name="rain"/></td>
                    <td><field name="glue_chip"/></td>
                    <td><field name="gray"/></td>
                    <td><field name="bronze"/></td>
                    <td><field name="tub_bypass"/></td>
                    <td><field name="shower_bypass"/></td>
                    <td><field name="other"/></td>
                    <td><field name="euro_tub"/></td>
                    <td><field name="euro_lite_shower"/></td>
                    <td><field name="semi_patch"/></td>
                    <td><field name="semi_comp"/></td>
                    <td><field name="euro"/></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">2</th>
                    <td><field name="size"/></td>
                    <td><field name="chrome"/></td>
                    <td><field name="plate"/></td>
                    <td><field name="bn"/></td>
                    <td><field name="champ"/></td>
                    <td><field name="brushed_nickel"/></td>
                    <td><field name="oil_rubbed"/></td>
                    <td><field name="aged_bz"/></td>
                    <td><field name="aged_pewter"/></td>
                    <td><field name="clear"/></td>
                    <td><field name="p62"/></td>
                    <td><field name="rain"/></td>
                    <td><field name="glue_chip"/></td>
                    <td><field name="gray"/></td>
                    <td><field name="bronze"/></td>
                    <td><field name="tub_bypass"/></td>
                    <td><field name="shower_bypass"/></td>
                    <td><field name="other"/></td>
                    <td><field name="euro_tub"/></td>
                    <td><field name="euro_lite_shower"/></td>
                    <td><field name="semi_patch"/></td>
                    <td><field name="semi_comp"/></td>
                    <td><field name="euro"/></td>

                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th scope="row">3</th>
                    <td><field name="size"/></td>
                    <td><field name="chrome"/></td>
                    <td><field name="plate"/></td>
                    <td><field name="bn"/></td>
                    <td><field name="champ"/></td>
                    <td><field name="brushed_nickel"/></td>
                    <td><field name="oil_rubbed"/></td>
                    <td><field name="aged_bz"/></td>
                    <td><field name="aged_pewter"/></td>
                    <td><field name="clear"/></td>
                    <td><field name="p62"/></td>
                    <td><field name="rain"/></td>
                    <td><field name="glue_chip"/></td>
                    <td><field name="gray"/></td>
                    <td><field name="bronze"/></td>
                    <td><field name="tub_bypass"/></td>
                    <td><field name="shower_bypass"/></td>
                    <td><field name="other"/></td>
                    <td><field name="euro_tub"/></td>
                    <td><field name="euro_lite_shower"/></td>
                    <td><field name="semi_patch"/></td>
                    <td><field name="semi_comp"/></td>
                    <td><field name="euro"/></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </group>
        <group class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="panel panel-default col-xs-4 col-md-2">
              <div class="panel-title">Order Size</div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-row form-group">
                  <field name="order_size_1" class="col input-sm" placeholder=""/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row form-group">
                  <field name="order_size_2" class="col input-sm" placeholder=""/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row form-group">
                  <field name="order_size_3" class="col input-sm" placeholder=""/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row form-group">
                  <field name="order_size_4" class="col input-sm" placeholder=""/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
              <div class="">Insert photo of sketch</div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group ">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">Take Shot
                  </div>
                  <field name="sketch" class="input-sm" id="hand-drawn-sketch"/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default col-xs-4 col-md-4">
              <div class="panel-title">Kits</div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-group input-group input-group-sm">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="input-group-text">Screw Pack</span>
                  </div>
                  <field name="screw_pack"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group input-group-sm">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="input-group-text">Vinyl</span>
                  </div>
                  <field name="vinyl"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group input-group-sm">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="input-group-text">Gussets</span>
                  </div>
                  <field name="gussetts"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group input-group-sm">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="input-group-text">Sill</span>
                  </div>
                  <field name="sill"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group input-group-sm">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="input-group-text">Header</span>
                  </div>
                  <field name="header"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group input-group-sm">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="input-group-text">Jamb</span>
                  </div>
                  <field name="jamb"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group input-group-sm">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="input-group-text">Thin Sill</span>
                  </div>
                  <field name="thin_sill"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group input-group-sm">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="input-group-text">Neo Post</span>
                  </div>
                  <field name="neo_post"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group input-group-sm">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="input-group-text">ADJ Post</span>
                  </div>
                  <field name="adj_post"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group input-group-sm">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="input-group-text">Expander Post</span>
                  </div>
                  <field name="expander_post"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group input-group-sm">
                  <div class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="input-group-text">Door Kit with Door</span>
                  </div>
                  <field name="door_kits_with_door"/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </group>
        <group>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="panel panel-default col-md-6">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-row form-group">
                  <label for="date_completed"/>
                  <field name="date_completed" class="col" placeholder="Date"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row form-group">
                  <label for="completed_by"/>
                  <field name="completed_by" class="col" placeholder="Name"/>
                </div>
                <div class="card-title">Installed, Door Built, Correct Glass and Color Initials</div>
                <div class="form-row form-group">
                  <label for="installed_date"/>
                  <field name="install_date" class="col" placeholder="Date"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row form-group">
                  <label for="installed_by"/>
                  <field name="installed_by" class="col" placeholder="Name"/>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default col-md-6">
              <div class="panel-heading">Notes</div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="form-row form-group">
                  <label for="notes"/>
                  <field name="notes" class="col" rows="4" placeholder="Notes"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-row form-group">
                  <div class="form-check mx-2 mr-sm-2">
                    <label for="send_mirror_with_job"/>
                    <field name="send_mirror_with_job" class="form-check-input"/>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </group>
      </sheet>
    </form>
  </field>
</record>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your issue it's not related with the field shower_form, as shows the image link

[image]

Is more related to the field `current_activity_names` that seems to be using the operator `not like` that is a valid operator for server side usage but not supported by the web client for client side usage

Comment: But `current_activity_names` has never been an issue as when other similar fields were added.   
More specifically, background colors based on Javascript no longer work, buttons added as widgets no turns to a Char field

Comment: Then seems that your issue is not what you think it was. Perhaps you need to provide more details or a way to test it

Comment: I got the issue fixed now. What happened was in shower_form.xml i imported bootstrap and my custom css. 
This was overwriting the other js and css files i called in my template document. To fix this I had to remove these to my templete doc. 
Many thanks for help me out